# Manipulating HTML snippet after jQuery load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on loading a HTML table snippet into a page via jQuery Load.

When this snippet is loaded into the page will i be able to manipulate the table with jQuery or is it just treated as a string?

When i say manipulate i have onClick events on table columns that need to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, and make sure that your events are binded after the new elements are loaded into the DOM. Else, have a look at the `live` function.

Comment: I think all the events are attached to the HTML itself of the newly loaded controls.

Answer (score 4):

If you insert your loaded snippet into the page (which is pretty much automatic in jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)), it will become part of the DOM, and can be treated exactly like any HTML element that was originally on the page.

Comment: but beware, the events you bound before the load will not apply to this new DOM part. to get this behavior you need to use live events see http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Yes i did some POC work with and without using the .live() method and it works great!

Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update if someone stumbles upon this thread again.

`.live()` is deprecated from jquery 1.7.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the **.live()** method is deprecated. Use **.on()** to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use **.delegate()** in preference to **.live()**.

http://api.jquery.com/live/